# Bootstrap 3.0.2 - Link content from one tab-pane to content in another

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm need to create a link from one tab-pane to content in another tab-pane.
For example, I have an overview tab and want to link to a specific image in the gallery tab, i.e. when I click on the link, it should make the other tab active and move to the correct place in the gallery.

I loaded the code here http://jsfiddle.net/tyec07rx/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#overview-panel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery-panel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gallery</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="overview-panel" class="tab-pane active">
                <p>We have new <a href="#sticker-packs">sticker kits</a> for your capri.</p>
                <p>Options:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#target">Target</a></li>
                    <li>British flag</li>
                    <li>Stripes</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="gallery-panel" class="tab-pane">
            <p>Image of sticker packs to go here</p>
            <p class="sticker-packs">Clicked link from Overview should get here...</p>

            <ul>
                <li class="target">Target sticker image (click through from Overview should get here)</li>
                <li>British sticker image</li>
                <li>Stripe sticker image</li>
            </ul>

        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have two tabs, overview & gallery. In the overview tab there is a lot of information and I would like people to be able to click on a hyperlink (in the overview tab), that takes them to a speciufic image in the gallery tab. In other words when they click on the link "sticker kits", the gallery tab should become active and the page scrolls to the "sticker kit" image.

Comment: Do you really mean 3.0.2 and not 3.2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a two step procedure :

> link to content -> open tab -> scroll to content

This cannot be done natively by bootstrap. To achieve this, we must know what tab each link targets, and the id of the element we want to scroll to. Change the link above to

```
<li><a href="#target" data-tab="#gallery-panel">Target</a></li>
```

where `href` is the `id` of the target in `.tab-content`, and `data-tab` is the id of the tab we want to open. We can now implement a click function that performs the tab switch and final scrolling :

```
$("a[data-tab]").on('click', function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
        target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('ul.nav a[href="' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1);    
});
```

Now, if you want to have a link to another tab, all you need is to define `data-tab` and of course have a valid `id` as `href`.

see working demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/k5Lv95L1/**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/kyzzLTxSCR)

HTML::

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#overview-panel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a id="li" href="#gallery-panel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gallery</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="overview-panel" class="tab-pane active">
                <p>We have new <a href="#sticker-packs">sticker kits</a> for your capri.</p>
                <p>Options:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="btn" href="#target">Target</a></li>
                    <li>British flag</li>
                    <li>Stripes</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="gallery-panel" class="tab-pane">
                <p>Image of sticker packs to go here</p>
                <p class="sticker-packs">Clicked link from Overview should get here...</p>

                <ul>
                    <li class="target">Target sticker image (click through from Overview should get here)</li>
                    <li>British sticker image</li>
                    <li>Stripe sticker image</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
  $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#li").click();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used davidkonrad's solution as it's a better fit for what I need right now.